# SQLite: how to LIMIT a subquery for GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sqlite, subquery, limit

I have a subquery that feeds a GROUP_CONCAT. All works well except the LIMIT, which does not have the effect I want.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Animal (
    id  TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,
    diet    TEXT
    );
INSERT INTO Animal VALUES ('monkey',    'herbivore');
INSERT INTO Animal VALUES ('goat',  'herbivore');
INSERT INTO Animal VALUES ('cat',   'carnivore');
INSERT INTO Animal VALUES ('dog',   'omnivore');
INSERT INTO Animal VALUES ('human', 'omnivore');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Domicile (
    id  TEXT    PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Animal,
    home    TEXT
    );

INSERT INTO Domicile VALUES ('monkey',  'jungle');
INSERT INTO Domicile VALUES ('goat',    'farmyard');
INSERT INTO Domicile VALUES ('cat', 'house');
INSERT INTO Domicile VALUES ('dog', 'garden');
INSERT INTO Domicile VALUES ('human',   'house');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Food (
    name    TEXT    PRIMARY KEY
    );

INSERT INTO Food VALUES ('fruit');
INSERT INTO Food VALUES ('meat');
INSERT INTO Food VALUES ('fish');
INSERT INTO Food VALUES ('bread');
INSERT INTO Food VALUES ('sausages');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Eats (
    id  TEXT    REFERENCES Animal,
    name    TEXT    REFERENCES Food
    );

INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('monkey',  'fruit');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('monkey',  'bread');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('goat',    'fruit');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('cat',     'meat');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('cat',     'sausages');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('dog',     'meat');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('dog',     'bread');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('dog',     'sausages');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('human',   'fruit');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('human',   'meat');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('human',   'fish');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('human',   'bread');
INSERT INTO Eats VALUES ('human',   'sausages');

.mode column

SELECT 'TEST 4: JOIN Eats using a subquery to order the names.';
SELECT      Animal.id,
        Animal.diet,
        GROUP_CONCAT (Eats.name) as names,
        Domicile.home
FROM        Animal
        INNER JOIN Domicile USING (id)
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM Eats
            ORDER BY name
            ) as Eats USING (id)
GROUP BY    Animal.id
ORDER BY    Animal.id
;
SELECT 'TEST 4 result: names in order, but not limited to 3.';

SELECT 'TEST 5: LIMIT Eats subquery to 3.';
SELECT      Animal.id,
        Animal.diet,
        GROUP_CONCAT (Eats.name) as names,
        Domicile.home
FROM        Animal
        INNER JOIN Domicile USING (id)
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM Eats
            ORDER BY name
            LIMIT 3
            ) as Eats USING (id)
GROUP BY    Animal.id
ORDER BY    Animal.id
;
SELECT 'TEST 5 result: LIMIT has applied to wrong SELECT?.';
```

What I want is output like this:

```
id      diet       names                home
------  ---------  -------------------  --------
cat     carnivore  meat,sausages        house
dog     omnivore   bread,meat,sausages  garden
goat    herbivore  fruit                farmyard
human   omnivore   bread,fish,fruit     house
monkey  herbivore  bread,fruit          jungle
```

Notes:

1. Rows ordered by 'id'.
2. Not every possible combination is present in Eats.
   (eg goat only eats fruit).
3. 'names' column in alphabetical order and limited to 3 elements
   (else 'human' would be bread,fish,fruit,meat,sausages).

What I get from the two tests is this:

```
'TEST 4: JOIN Eats using a subquery to order the names.'
--------------------------------------------------------
TEST 4: JOIN Eats using a subquery to order the names.  
id      diet       names                           home    
------  ---------  ------------------------------  --------
cat     carnivore  meat,sausages                   house   
dog     omnivore   bread,meat,sausages             garden  
goat    herbivore  fruit                           farmyard
human   omnivore   bread,fish,fruit,meat,sausages  house   
monkey  herbivore  bread,fruit                     jungle  
'TEST 4 result: names in order, but not limited to 3.'
------------------------------------------------------
TEST 4 result: names in order, but not limited to 3.  
'TEST 5: LIMIT Eats subquery to 3.'
-----------------------------------
TEST 5: LIMIT Eats subquery to 3.  
id      diet       names  home  
------  ---------  -----  ------
dog     omnivore   bread  garden
human   omnivore   bread  house 
monkey  herbivore  bread  jungle
'TEST 5 result: LIMIT has applied to wrong SELECT?.'
----------------------------------------------------
TEST 5 result: LIMIT has applied to wrong SELECT?.
```

The only difference between the source of tests 4 and 5 is the LIMIT in the test 5 subquery.

Is there a way to limit the names to, say, 3 elements? (I would want the limit to be easily changeable.)

Comment: You are limiting subquery Eats to 3 rows of base Eats. The names in the rows will be bread, bread & bread. Also you are not limiting names to 3 (distinct) names per id. PS Don't use 'Eats' for 2 different tables. PS ORDER BY without TOP/LIMIT not at the outermost level has no effect. Tables have no row order; query result sets [sic] have (partial) order per an outermost ORDER BY. So in a SELECT not at the outermost level either use both ORDER BY & LIMIT or neither. PS Your bullets are not clear.Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: It's good that you tried to make a [mre] but you don't actually confirm that the table values you are joining or other intermediate results are correct. You changed 1 line, but deep inside expressions; you need to isolate to what is happening at that point. PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & seldom ask what the asker actually wants answered.

Comment: philipxy - thanks so much for your help, which must have taken you a fair amount of time. In reply to your point re my clarity and asking the right question, all I can say is that I did look at what I wrote and did think about it. But obviously not enough. My final yes/no question should have been written as a "how do I" question. In any case, I have been studying your solution and it looks good, though one detail I have not fixed yet is getting the names into alphabetical order inside the group_concat. I'm relatively new to SQL but enjoying the learning.

Comment: I have made a couple of minor edits to your solution and posted it in the main post above. All seems to be working perfectly now.

Comment: I didn't post an answer, these are comments. My comment re debugging vs advancing & my "yes or no" sentence are pre-fab. Others: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. An answer does not belong in a question post & indication of being answered does not belong in a question title. Please roll back & post an answer in an answer post. Accept an answer by clicking on the check mark icon after minimum wait time to show it is the best answer. You can get the raw text of your answer by clicking on 'edited' then cut & paste into an answer.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: Please edit per my comments. (But don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable answer posts.) PS A dump of non-working code or a specification (especially an unarticulated one with 1 example) just is not a good contribution to the site. This isn't a help desk, it is a repository of good & searchable/findable Q&A. You can expect that when you pin this down via an actual [mre] & clearly phrase it it will be a faq. [tour] [meta] [meta.se] PS Your last comment above seems to have been intended for the answer post, not this question post.

Comment: See my comments on the answer post.

Comment: In your answer that I rolled back: Again: The nested ORDER BYs do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following is a solution (that is hopefully relatively easy to understand):-

```
WITH
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT 
            animal.*,
            domicile.home,
            eats.name 
        FROM animal 
        JOIN eats ON eats.id = animal.id 
        JOIN domicile ON domicile.id = animal.id
        ORDER BY animal.id,eats.id
        ),
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT *, (
            SELECT count(*) FROM cte1 AS cte1_c 
            WHERE cte1_c.name <= cte1.name AND cte1_c.id = cte1.id ORDER BY id,name
        ) AS c 
        FROM cte1
    )
SELECT id,diet,group_concat(name) AS names,home FROM cte2 WHERE c <= 3 GROUP BY id;
```

- basically the core data (cte1) has the number of eats that are less or the same appended thus allowing the final WHERE clause to limit the number of eats per group

Which results in:-

[image]

How many **names** is easily changed  by altering the number in the final WHERE clause `WHERE c <= 3`

e.g. amending the data where your first select produces:-

[image]

- i.e. human has 9 foods/names

Using the solution but with `WHERE c <= 5` then:-

[image]

Using **1** results in:-

[image]

The flaw is if using less than **1** in which case no data will be output.

**Additional**

This is very much the same as the answer but amended to:-

1. hopefully make it easier to understand (comments and name of the subquery for the count changed), and
2. to correctly order the food names for the group_concat

:-

```
WITH
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT 
            animal.*,
            domicile.home,
            eats.name 
        FROM animal 
        JOIN eats ON eats.id = animal.id 
        JOIN domicile ON domicile.id = animal.id
        ORDER BY animal.id,eats.id
        ),
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            /* Use a subquery to ascertain the number (count) of names in cte1 that 
                a) have the the same name as the name being processed, OR 
                c) a name that is less than the current name being processed, AND
                b) have the same id as the currrent id being processed 
            */
            (
                SELECT 
                    count(*) 
                    FROM cte1 AS query_of_all_of_cte1
                WHERE 
                    query_of_all_of_cte1.name <= cte1.name /* cte1.name is the name from the current row being processed */ 
                AND 
                    query_of_all_of_cte1.id = cte1.id /* cte1.id is the id from the current row being processed */
            
            ) 
            /* the column name rather than defaulting to count(*) is aliaseed as c */
                AS c 
        FROM cte1 ORDER BY id,name
    )
SELECT id,diet,group_concat(name) AS names,home FROM cte2 WHERE c <= 3 GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: ORDER BY without TOP/LIMIT not at the outermost level has no effect. Your ORDER BYs are pointless & your query result has no guaranteed order. Also the question bullet 3 asks for the CSVs to each be ordered but this code does not guarantee that (as demonstrated in one of your results).

Comment: I don't understand this. You have "SELECT count(*) FROM cte1 AS cte1_c WHERE cte1_c.name <= cte1.name AND cte1_c.id = cte1.id ORDER BY id,name". So "cte1_c" is an alias for the table being defined by the SELECT, and which must have exactly one column, namely the COUNT. Yet you refer to other columns, namely "cte1_c.name" and "cte1_c.id". I guess these other columns are from in "cte1" but if I take away the aliasing and just use "cte1" instead of "cte1_c" the WHERE clause simply matches all rows. Could you possibly explain this apparent contradiction (or my misunderstanding)? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeT - Just been looking up the syntax of tables aliases - I had this one wrong. In "SELECT count(*) FROM cte1 AS cte1_c" the name "cte1_c" is an alias for "cte1", not for the result of the SELECT. That explains how cte1_c has all the necessary columns. Still a bit puzzled by how the SELECT works, since I would expect a WHERE test like "cte1_c.name <= cte1.name" to always be true if "cte1_c" is an alias for "cte1". Different sets of rows I guess. But I feel one step closer.

Comment: @NormanofAnstruther `cte1` is referring to the current subquery i.e. the single current output row being built/processed. `cte1_c` refers to cte1 again (all the source data). Perhaps explained by:- Get the number of rows from the original/source (`cte1_c`) where the name is less than or the same as the row currently being processed by the subquery AND where the id in the original/source is the same as the row currently being processed. As the columns names are the same name they need to be disambiguated.  Sorry had the CTE names the wrong way round. Corrected.

Comment: @NormanofAnstruther see the **Additional** which will hopefully better explain how the count is derived